# Why the reason of closing a post is automatically attached to the reason of the majority?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, close-reasons

Names of people who have voted to temporarily close a question appear on top of it, along with the reason of the closing.

But if 4 people decided to close the post based on reason A and the 5th person decided to close it upon reason B, then his or her name will be appended to the list and only linked to reason A.

Hence it's not reflecting his or her own reason for closing that post.

Is it possible to change this behaviour on our side or is this inherent to the design of the overall site?

Comment: No we can't change it for just this site, but you could ask at [meta.se] (or perhaps there's already a Q&A there)

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Midavalo, this Stack Exchange software behaviour is not configurable on a per-site basis, and to have that behaviour altered you would need to use Meta Stack Exchange (rather than GIS Meta) where there is an existing feature request at
[Distinguish close votes by reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-close-votes-by-reason).